# file upload control

Tags: asp.net, upload, file-upload

asp.net provides file upload control....
now if i want to upload files on my server, do i need to manage the file transfer protocall for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It does everything for you.

Comment: i m confused with file upload control and file transfer protocall... .net 2.0 provides the FTPWebRequest and FTPWebResponse classes for file uploading...why is it given sepratly? can you please tell me? thanks

Comment: Those are for FTP; the upload control does it via HTTP (as posted above).

Comment: They'd be for uploading to other servers.

Answer (score 3):

No, the control uses the HTTP protocol to upload files to your Web server.

Answer (score 1):

On submit simply inspect the properties of the fileupload control: HasFile and PostedFile are the main two.